# onchange cannot use?

Tags: javascript, ajax, onchange

```
function gettime(str) {

        var strURL="/Doctor/booking/gettime.jsp?datepicker="+str;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('d11').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
<b>Date:<input id="d11" type="text" name="datepicker" onClick="WdatePicker()" onchange="gettime(this.value)"/></b>
```

When I click the textbox, alert a datepicker and choose a date, the textbox should change its value. But it doesn't. What way can I solve it?

Moreover, when I directly enter this url: /Doctor/booking/gettime.jsp?datepicker=2012-02-02 I see the output that I want.

Comment: You should be aware that `onchange` fires after field loses the focus. Anyway, I assume there is an error... what does it say?

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging it? You know Firebug/Chrome console/Dragonfly? You should post the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

instead of:

```
document.getElementById('d11').innerHTML=req.responseText;
```

try:

```
document.getElementById('d11').value=req.responseText;
```

Comment: sorry, i fix it. the id is wrong. the id is the first drop down list id, not the second drop down list id.

Comment: So, you've managed to solve the problem? If so and my answer was helpful, please accept it. Otherwise create your own answer and accept it.